# Dynamic windows (Boxes) and elements in blessed (nodejs text UI library)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use blessed, a text UI lib for Node. I'd like to create windows dynamically (free them after use), but I could not find info in the docs about how to destroy them.

I've tried to remove the created Box object from it's parent (the Screen) and drop any references to it, so Node's GC could do the rest, but it doesn't seem to work, presumably a reference is leaking somewhere.

The examples I could find does not do anything like this, they all create a bunch of windows, hide them and show them when needed again.

Has anyone any clue how to do this, or this is not supported?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [remove method](https://github.com/chjj/blessed#methods) to do it.
For example, if you append a form (with screen as parent) to screen using: `screen.append(form);` you can destroy the form using `screen.remove(form);` it works well.

Example:

```
var form = blessed.form({
      parent: screen,
      width: '50%',
      height: 7,
      border: {
        type: 'line'
      },
      keys: true,
      tags: true,
      top: 'center',
      left: 'center'
    });

var cancel = blessed.button({
  parent: form,
  mouse: true,
  keys: true,
  shrink: true,
  padding: {
    left: 1,
    right: 1
  },
  left: 48,
  width: 9,
  top: 3,
  name: 'cancel',
  content: 'cancel',
  style: {
    focus: {
       bg: 'blue',
       fg: 'white'
    },
    hover: {
      bg: 'blue',
      fg: 'white'
    }
  },
  border: {
    type: 'line'
  }
});

var submit = blessed.button({
  parent: form,
  mouse: true,
  keys: true,
  shrink: true,
  padding: {
    left: 1,
    right: 1
  },
  left: 35,
  width: 9,
  top: 3,
  name: 'submit',
  content: 'submit',
  style: {
    focus: {
       bg: 'blue',
       fg: 'white'
    },
    hover: {
      bg: 'blue',
      fg: 'white'
    }
  },
  border: {
    type: 'line'
  }
});

screen.append(form);
submit.focus();
screen.render();

cancel.on('press', function() {
  screen.remove(form);
  screen.render();
});
```